# chattr - How to change file +i attribute without using chattr

Tags: linux, security, unix

Here`s the problem. My server got probably hacked. I would like to change a config file, but it is immutable (has the +i attribute), so I can't edit it.

trying to execute a "chattr -i" on the file does not work because I don't have execute write on chattr command.

Trying a chmod on the chattr command does not work because the chattr command has the +i attribute too.

Is there a way to remove the attribute without using chattr?

The server got hacked and probably will need a fresh re-install but meanwhile I need a temporary solution.

Comment: What operating system/version/distribution?

Comment: Linux cdr2-245 2.6.18-194.11.4.el5 #1 SMP Tue Sep 21 05:04:09 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Yes, you need a reinstall...and update the system more often than once every four years.

Answer (score 3):

Just make a copy of chattr and use that copy to remove the immutable bit.

```
[root@c7 bin]# ls -lh chattr;lsattr chattr
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 12K Jun  9 19:59 chattr
----i----------- chattr
[root@c7 bin]# cp chattr chattr.new
[root@c7 bin]# chmod a+x chattr.new
[root@c7 bin]# chattr.new -i chattr
[root@c7 bin]# rm -f chattr.new
[root@c7 bin]# chmod a+x chattr
[root@c7 bin]# ls -lh chattr;lsattr chattr
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 12K Jun  9 19:59 chattr
---------------- chattr
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I just tried it and chattr.new -i does not seem to have an effect. It runs with no errors, but nothing happens. Here's the chattr attributes: s---ia------- chattr

Comment: What is the output of capsh --print?

Comment: Start by `touch`-ing an empty file, set the correct permissions on it and then copy chattr to that file?